# Divide a triangle into two equal parts through a point on it.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

Let *E* be the midpoint of *AC*; let D be a arbitrary point on *AC*. Draw *BD*; draw *EF* parallel to *BD*. Then *DF* divides the triangle in half. How to prove it?

I know that *△AFE* is equal in area to *△EFC* for it is on the same base and in the same parallels (I.38 Euclid), however I don't know how to use this fact.

I also know that equality can be proved if *△ABF* is shown to be two times the area of *△DFE*.

[image]

Comment: hint: $A_{ABF} : A_{AFC}= BF : FC$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Medians divide triangles in two halves.
[image]

Comment: Huh, that's so simple! I fixated on the wrong thing. Thanks!